# What do I need to use adjective 'active selected' or adverb 'actively selected'?

Tags: adjectives, american-english, british-english, adverbs

In my commit message, I wrote something like:

> -disabled search button if there is no active selected filter

and I got the following warning from my Integrated Development Environment (IDE)

> A. Make sure that the adjective ‘active’ is correct. Possibly, it should be an adverb (typically ~Iy) that modifies ‘selected'. Possibly, it should be the first word in 2 compound adjective (hyphenated adjective). Possibly, it is correct.

[image]

Could you please clarify the situation how to write it correctly?
thanks in advance

Comment: google suggests - integrated development environment,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "active selected filter", "active" is an adjective. It qualifies the noun phrase "selected filter", and the meaning is equivalent to "selected filter which is active". This is presumably the meaning you intend.

If you write "actively selected filter", "actively" is an adverb. Adverbs modify verbs and adjectives, so in this case it qualifies the adjective "selected". This phrase would mean "filter that was selected in an active manner". I doubt this is what you mean to say.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer i was looking for.

P.s.: strange that the text editor offered me the wrong version

Comment: @AshBadCoder Text editors have their limitations. The English language is complex and often defeats them.